# Is it possible to use Arabic as a resource "culture Language" on WP7?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

I understand WP7 support limited number of language as Culture for localization BUT Silverlight itself support more language so my question is Can I make culture info take arguments of "any from supported language" and in resource file string write my own "needed" to support language in my app in this case it's Arabic language ?? 
in other words file resource.fr.resx and supply strings with Arabic data ?
Will it pass for certification?

Answer (score 1):

For Windows Phone 7 i wrote a mapping function which maps the Arabic encoding[windows-1256] into default WP7 encoding.

```
public static string ConvertToArabic(string s)
        {
            short[] mapping = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 8364, 1662, 8218, 402, 8222, 8230, 8224, 8225, 710, 8240, 1657, 8249, 338, 1670, 1688, 1672, 1711, 8216, 8217, 8220, 8221, 8226, 8211, 8212, 1705, 8482, 1681, 8250, 339, 8204, 8205, 1722, 160, 1548, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 1726, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 1563, 187, 188, 189, 190, 1567, 1729, 1569, 1570, 1571, 1572, 1573, 1574, 1575, 1576, 1577, 1578, 1579, 1580, 1581, 1582, 1583, 1584, 1585, 1586, 1587, 1588, 1589, 1590, 215, 1591, 1592, 1593, 1594, 1600, 1601, 1602, 1603, 224, 1604, 226, 1605, 1606, 1607, 1608, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 1609, 1610, 238, 239, 1611, 1612, 1613, 1614, 244, 1615, 1616, 247, 1617, 249, 1618, 251, 252, 8206, 8207, 1746 };

        string str = string.Empty;
        for (int ix = 0; ix < s.Length; ++ix)
        {
            str = str +  (char)mapping[s[ix]];
        }
        return str;
    }
```

This worked for me perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone 7 does not support Arabic character sets (But Windows Phone 8 will).

Some applications have worked around this with custom fonts but this approach will require lots of careful testing.

Comment: I know but my question is this App will pass the certificate ?? with current settings as I mentioned ?

Comment: @Mohab it will probably depend on if you're supporting multiple languages, how you're using the cultureinfo and what the consequence of the user putting their phone into French is?

Comment: it will display app language default as Arabic but he can change it from inside to other languages